# Visual Studio Team Services Could not load file or assembly 'classlibrary' or one of its dependencies when changed to build branch solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We've got an agent build working on the main development branch from Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

[image: TFS Source Control Window]

With our agent build configuration set as:

[image]

This is working fine, the build agent picks up the source and builds.

Now, I want to make the build agent build the R5 code which is identical to the Main Dev Trunk code - newly created branch.

[image]

So in VSTS I change the folder to build to:

[image]

When a file is checked in it triggers the build. It builds no problem.

But for some reason I getting this error when loading the website.

> "Could not load file or assembly 'classlibxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified."

The code is identical, so must some setting in VSTS?

Do I need to change anything else in VSTS, is the path correct, or what else could it be?

UPDATE - what I do notice now is that the log is telling me it is download all the sources (even for the previous R1-R4 releases)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! Since it's way TL/DR to wade through the, what I'm finding is very poor, documentation for VSTS... Here is what was causing it:

The mystic _work directories of the agent...  E.g. c:\agent\1,2 etc. are NOT output directories.

The website had been pointed to one of these folders and by some fluke must have been working.

What is needed is another step in the Build Definition to actually place the compiled files into something meaningful.

[image]

You need to supply an Admin Username and password even if it on a drive local to the Agent.

But hey presto, after 6hrs of madness... all the projects are lined up and will run without issue.